# UITableView Cells Expand With A Delay

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am making a to do list app and have 3 custom cell types. For task cells, it is just an imageview on the left and a textview on the right. I would like the cell to automatically resize itself when the textview text is to large for a single line.

I have added the correct constraints and have added this to viewWillAppear

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

However, when going into the view with the tableview, the cells remain small for a second and then expand to their correct size. Also, when initially adding the task, the cell doesn't resize unless either going back and opening the view controller again or the tableview is scrolled up until the cell is out of view and then letting go.

This is very odd behaviour and even happens when removing the two lines above from viewWillAppear. It just happens for no reason.

I would like the cells to be of the right size when going into the view and not resizing a second later.

An example of what this looks like is below

[image: Example]

Comment: This probably happens because you specified `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight`. You should keep only one. Have you tried to move these lines to `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: @YuryBogdanov I have tried moving them to view did load, removing one and even removing both lines entirely and the behaviour still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally found the answer. I made my cell programmatically with auto layout and some of that was setup in the layoutSubviews() method inside the cell. This method is only called when needed. So when scrolling up or down.

To fix this, in your cellForRowAt method, just call

```
cell.layoutSubviews()
```

Comment: It's not very clean solution, since you shouldn't call `layoutSubviews()` directly (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews). Use `layoutIfNeeded()` if you are absolutely sure.